# Send contribution receipt when updating contribution via API

Tags: civicontribute

On my CiviCRM site, I have a v3 API to update the status of a pending contribution (for payments sent offline). The current PHP code for this is the following:

```
$params = array( 
  'contribution_id' => $contribid,
  'payment_instrument_id' => 4, // check = 4
  'note' => 'Contribution record updated via group updater',
  'contribution_status_id' => 1,
  'version' => 3,
);

$result = civicrm_api( 'contribution','create',$params );
```

This works well, but I would like to be able to send a receipt to the person that submitted this contribution via this API call. Is that doable?

Answer (score 3):

I found my own answer in this api function:

```
civicrm_api3('contribution', 'sendconfirmation', array('id' => $result['id']));
```

This triggers the confirmation email to be sent.

P.S. I wish there was something similar for the Event Participants, that seems to be quite trickier.